# Online automated regression or functionality testing options

Tags: ui-automation, functional-testing, browser-automation, regression-testing

I am searching for an online service that allows me to automate certain regression or functionality tests.  I would like the ability to use a browser based screen recording plugin like e52.com and ghostinspector.com have.  I like ghostinspector.com the best so far but was wondering what tools you like best that may be alternatives to these.

Answer (score 0):

Ghostinspector seems based on Selenium, so I think knowing and implement tests directly via Selenium will provide you more control if you may spend some time in Coding. But for those who are looking for quick solutions or learning Selenium, may find ghostinspector useful.